vue List Rendering: change value of string before "v-for"
I am trying to replace a certain string with a condition before it gets to the output.
Below is my code
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const items = ref([{ letter: "A", message: '1' }, { letter: "B", message: '2' }])
</script>

<template>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <p v-if="item.message === '1'">
            {{ item.letter }} - {{ 'Apple' }}
        </p>
        <p v-if="item.message === '2'">
            {{ item.letter }} - {{ 'Banana' }}
        </p>
    </li>
</template>

I tried adding the v-if inside the v-for but this seems impractical. I am trying to figure out a way to have item.message replace its string value before v-for. Any suggestions?

Your question is unclear. Edit your question and add 1. what code produces, and 2. what do you wish that code to produce instead

You can remap your items array with map function.

What about a Computed Property?
This derives one value from other values (it's dependencies). This seems a perfect case here.
You can declared it like this:
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'


const displayItems = computed(() => {
  return items.value.map(item => {
    if (item.message === '1') {
      return `${item.letter} - Apple`
    }
    if (item.message === '2') {
      return `${item.letter} - Banana`
    }
    return `${item.letter} - unknown`
  })
})

And replace your template with this:
<li v-for="item in displayItems">
      <span> {{ item }}</span>
</li>

